# Is this third person?

Tags: questions

I will ask people by their proper name how they are.

> How is Mary today?

Is this talking to them in third person?

Comment: Could you say "Mary, how are you today ?" or "How are you today, Mary ?" ?

Comment: "How **is Mary** today?" is 3rd person (e.g. **She is** fine). You are not asking Mary directly, so you use 3rd person.

Comment: @JamesWirth I think Abigail is talking about asking Mary directly, but in the third person, e.g. "And how is Mary today?" or "How is my favorite coworker today?"

Comment: So this is how the senerio is...I answer my phone and the person on the other end making the call announces themself as Mary.  My reply is "how is Mary today?" is this also 3rd person?

Comment: @jameswirth I was greeted by Mary and I replied with the question "how is Mary today?"  how or is this third person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking in third person is speaking about one's self. For example, if your name is Abigail and you were speaking to Mary, you could say "Abigail is good today." That is one example of using third person.